# How to add an InputMask plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, extjs, ext.net

How to add an InputMask plugin, and a mask, in a textfield dynamically, via JS?

I already tried:

```
field.addPlugins(new InputMask(
{
    Mask: result
}));
```

but didn't work.

Comment: If you're using Ext.NET, try configuring the component using ASP.NET, then after the page renders in the browser, View > Source to see what JavaScript is created.

Comment: Very good idea, but when .net search for the file inputmask.js I'm receiving a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question are negativated but I find the answer.

Can be usefull one day!

It's necessary to register the plugin before use it! To do that just put:

```
ResourceManager.RegisterControlResources<InputMask>();
```

in PageLoad event.

Comment: The solution was provided in the following thread, see http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?23573-How-to-add-an-InputMask-plugin